# How to compile library for multiple platforms

Tags: linux, build, compilation, cross-platform, static-libraries

I'm Windows user, and I'm using VS2015 to compile my С++ projects for Windows.
But I need to compile my library for multiple platfroms, such as Linux, Android, HTML5, PlayStation 4, iOS.

But I have no any experience with this.

My target is uploading to market plugin for Unreal Engine 4 and I want to see my plugin worked on all platforms.

How to do it? Many of these platforms are based on Unix. Does this mean that compile enough under Linux?

[image: platforms]

Comment: _Many of these platforms are based on Unix. Does this mean that compile enough under Linux?_

**I think so no.**

Answer (score 0):

For cross-compilation you have to followed [instructions](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Compiling_For_Linux)
Also for compiling by Mac and HTML5 you have to clone source code from git. [More details here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine)

Comment: I need to compile my own static library, not UE4 source code.

And after link to my UE4 project (next step, not this topic)...